# Error 401 on AdminApp deployment to Websphere 9 Docker

Tags: docker, deployment, websphere, jython

While running jython py script with adminApp.install to install on Docker WAS, I'm getting the Error:

> WASX7017E: Exception received while running file
>   "deployWebSphere_with_install_standAlone.py"; exception information:
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.filetransfer.client.TransferFailedException:
>   401 Unauthorized (for:
>   C:\Users\devopsjava\AppData\Local\Temp\app5674632847255103189.ear).

I tried give full control on this path,
I tried set custom `property:com.ibm.websphere.management.filetransfer.serverBasicAuth=true`
(https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK71800)

My code:

```
options = ['-node ',node,'-cell ',cell,"-server ",server]
print AdminApp.install(packageFile, options)
```

I always get :

> WASX7017E: Exception received while running file
>   "deployWebSphere_with_install_standAlone.py"; exception information:
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.filetransfer.client.TransferFailedException:
>   401 Unauthorized (for:
>   C:\Users\devopsjava\AppData\Local\Temp\app5674632847255103189.ear).

Maybe, I need to set some more property, or there is problem with security between docker domain and the outside world ?

Comment: Are you using the official WebSphere docker image or did you install WebSphere into an image yourself. If the latter, is the container a Windows-based one or a Linux-based one running on Windows via Docker Desktop. Are you invoking wsadmin.bat from inside the container or a separate copy from outside that connects via SOAP?

Comment: I'm using the official: https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-traditional/ . I'm invoking the wsadmin from outside server

Comment: Are you connecting via SOAP or using conntype NONE? I wonder if this issue has anything to do with the container at all, since that's a Windows path and wsadmin should be able to send the file over without access problems since it can work across physical machines over a network... In the logs dir of the profile you're invoking wsadmin from you should have a trace file that could go into more detail about what is wrong.